# "unable to load manifest" error after subscribe via RosSharp/RosBridge

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Unity and the RosSharp library I'm able to connect but unable to subscribe to any custom .msg types. The types are correctly named in the RosSharp dictionary and builds fine on the ROS side. After requesting to subscribe it will throw the error on the rosbridge socket terminal:

`unable to load the manifest for package ####. Caused by ####`

`ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros`

`ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share`

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Lane

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286397/%22unable-to-load-manifest%22-error-after-subscribe-via-rossharp/rosbridge/) by [Lane](https://answers.ros.org/users/34288/lane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-24**:
Is package `###` present in your workspace / installed on your system? Does `rospack find ####` return the expected output (in the same terminal as where you start the RosBridge nodes)? I don't see any Catkin workspace in the error output, so did you `source` it?

**Comment by [Lane](https://answers.ros.org/users/34288/lane/) on 2018-03-26**:
the package is present, `rospack find` identifies it and i did `source ./devel/setup.bash` after the catkin_make.

**Comment by [Lane](https://answers.ros.org/users/34288/lane/) on 2018-03-27**:
This works on a linux box, but fails on my VirtualBox VM - identical projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just making sure: the terminal where you started rosbridge also had `source`d the workspace `setup.bash`?

---

Edit:

> Wow, did not realize that was required for each new terminal.

Yes, that is needed in every terminal. See #q286466 for a recent question about this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lane](https://answers.ros.org/users/34288/lane/) on 2018-03-27**:
Wow, did not realize that was required for each new terminal. Seems to be working fine, thanks =)

**Comment by [Lane](https://answers.ros.org/users/34288/lane/) on 2018-03-27**:
run `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in the bridge terminal window.